# True or false simple algebra questions (centralizers, conjugacy classes, normal groups, abelian groups)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

Can someone please verify my answers to the following questions?

> Answer true or false to the following questions:
>
> 1. Two elements of a group in the same conjugacy class must have the same order
> 2. A group of order 24 can have 5 conjugacy distinct classes of cardinalities 1, 4,4,6, and 12 respectively.
> 3. The group $S_3$ has three conjugacy classes, of cardinalities 1, 2, and 3, respectively.
> 4. An element is in the center of a group $G$ if and only if its centralizer is all of $G$
> 5. Every group has at least one conjugacy class consisting of only one element
> 6. If $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then it is stable under the action of conjugation on $G$.
> 7. The group $\mathbb{Z}_{17} \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ has 34 distinct conjugacy classes
> 8. In any finite group $G$, the order of the centralizer of any element divides $|G|$.
> 9. In an abelian group, the centralizer of each element is trivial.
> 10. An abelian subgroup of a group is always normal

1. True. Let $x \in G$. Consider the element $gxg^{-1}$, where $g \in G$. Let $n$ be the order of $x$. Then, we have $(gxg^{-1})^n = g^nxg^{-n} = g^n g^{-n} = e$. So, we have just shown that the order of $y$ is less than or equal to the order of $x$ if $y$ is conjugate to $x$. But this implies that the orders of $x$ and $y$ are equal, since $x$ is conjugate to $y$ if and only if $y$ is conjugate to $x$ (and so the inequality holds both ways, so the orders must be equal).
2. False, since $1+4+4+6+12 \neq 24$
3. True. The conjugacy classes are $\{ e \}$, $\{ (1 2 3), (1 3 2) \}$, $\{ (1 2), ( 1 3), (2 3) \}$.
4. True. This is easy to see from the definitions.
5. True. The identity element comprises a conjugacy class consisting of only one element.
6. True, since $gHg^{-1} = H$, by definition.
7. True. The group $\mathbb{Z}_{17} \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ is abelian. Therefore, each element comprises a distinct conjugacy class. Since the order of the group is 34, there are 34 distinct conjugacy classes.
8. True. The centralizer of any element in a group $G$ forms a subgroup of $G$. Therefore, by Lagrange's theorem, the order of the centralizer divides $|G|$.
9. False. In an abelian group, the centralizer of each element is the entire group.
10. False. I can't seem to find a counter-example, but my intuition tells me that the statement is incorrect. Can someone please let me know of a counterexample?

Comment: By writing $(gxg^{-1})^n=g^nx^ng^{-n}$ you're assuming your group is abelian.

Comment: For a counter-example to 10, consider the group generated by the cycle $(12)$ in $S_3$. Similarly that generated by $(1234)$ in $S_4$.

Comment: Number one should be $(gxg^{-1})^{n}=gx^{n}g^{-1}$. Since, for instance, $(gxg^{-1})^2 = gxg^{-1}gxg^{-1}=gx^{2}g^{-1}$. By induction this generalizes.

Comment: It is not really a good practice to upload such question with lots of subquestions. If you have a doubt about the correctness of either solution you could ask about it, but some of the questions are quite straightforward and it seems you don't really have a problem with them.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I apologize for that.

Comment: If this isn't homework, where are these questions from?

Answer (score 2):

For $10$, take any [group $A_n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_group) with $n\ge 5$. It is well-known that such groups are simple, that is, they have no non-trivial, normal subgroups. But the subgroup generated by $(1,2)$ is certainly abelian.

I find the rest of answers ok.